# How to modify a txt file using jframe in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have data saved in txt file. I have loaded them in a jtable in one of my forms and I want to be able to edit the txt file using buttons in the GUI form.
Also if you can tell me why I have empty lines appearing in the jtable that will be very helpful.

```
    private void delbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    
}                                      

private void modifybtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                         

private void newpassActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                       

private void newusernameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

here is the view button code

```
    private void viewbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    
    try{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("logindata.txt"));
        String firstLine = br.readLine().trim();
        String[] columnsName = firstLine.split("/");
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)datatable.getModel();
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnsName);
       
        Object[] tableLines = br.lines().toArray();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < tableLines.length; i++)
        {
            String line = tableLines[i].toString().trim();
            String[] dataRow = line.split(",");
            model.addRow(dataRow);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ep){
        Logger.getLogger(people_info.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ep);
    }
}
```

here is how I saved data in txt file

```
    private void submitbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    String user = usertxt.getText();
    String pass = passwordtxt.getText();
    
    try
    {
        FileOutputStream ldata = new FileOutputStream("logindata.txt", true);
        PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(ldata);
        
        printer.println(user+","+pass+","+","+",");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"success, please login");
        printer.close();
        
        this.setVisible(false);
        login lg = new login();
        lg.setVisible(true);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error, please retry");
    }        
}
```

[image: here is how the GUI looks like]

Comment: Can you post the text file reading code and table populating code?

Comment: @AbrahamArnold I just made the edits can you check it out.

Comment: 1) *I want to be able to edit the txt file using buttons in the GUI form.* - then you need to recreate the text file by writing all the data in the table to the file.  2) *why I have empty lines appearing in the jtable* either you a) created the table with empty rows or your file has empty row. You need to debug your code.

Comment: @camickr well the txt file has not empty lines at all. That's why I cant figure out why I have empty data displaying in the jTable

Comment: @godopetza, did you read the first suggestion:  `a) created the table with empty rows `. The table won't create empty row unless you tell it to do so. You didn't post your code were you create the table and table model, which is why I stated you need to debug your code to see what you are doing.

Comment: @camickr please refer to the codes where I saved data to txt file and the viewbtnAction

Comment: @godopetza After `model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnsName);` add this code and try, `model.setRowCount(0);`

Comment: For better help sooner. [edit] to add a [mre]. Hard code the data from the text file.

Comment: The code where you save the data is irrelevant to the stated question. You stated the data in your file was correct. So the question is why do you have extra rows??? Where do you create those rows if the rows in the file are correct??? We can't answer that question because the problem is in code you have not posted. So you need to learn how to do basic debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after `model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnsName);` add `model.setRowCount(0);`